# How do you get the NSURLConnection delegate methods to trigger?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I can't seem to get the delegate methods to call, when I load the view associated with this class.. none of them fire. I'm sure it's something that I've overlooked but I can't for the life of me figure out why.

**DownloadUpdates.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DownloadUpdates : UIViewController

    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableData *responseData;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSURLConnection *connection;

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response;

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection;

@end
```

**DownloadUpdates.m**

The URL has been removed for privacy purposes, but it's just making a call to an API which will be returning JSON data. This URL functions as expected so it's an issue with the code.

```
#import "DownloadUpdates.h"

@interface DownloadUpdates ()

@end

@implementation DownloadUpdates

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)_connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    _responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"Response received");
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)_connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [_responseData appendData:data];
        NSLog(@"Data received");
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)_connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Unable to fetch data");
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)_connection
{
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[_responseData
                                                   length]);
//    NSString *txt = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_responseData encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"URL HERE"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60];

    _connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I'd appreciate any help / advice you can offer.

Comment: Though not required, you never declare your class to conform to any of `NSURLConnection`'s protocols.

Comment: This might sound obvious, but I've seen some strange things on SO. Have you actually set an object of this class as the delegate of the connection?

Comment: This is my first time using NSURLConnection. I'm not sure what you mean. (I haven't been doing this very long).

Comment: The proper way to make yourself the delegate is to 1) do as @Scott says and remove the delegate method declarations from your class's interface, and 2) declare your class like this: "@interface MyVC : UIViewController < NSURLConnectionDelegate>" everything in quotes.

Comment: Also, fyi.  NSURLConnection supplies a one-liner alternative to all this.  If you're not going to do anything but make the request and inspect the result, you can substitute NSURLConnection + (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*))handler.

Comment: It's going to be making a request and then handling the result (parsing it into core data). But yeah that's the only function of this class. 

I'm going to blame the heat / fact I've been sat in front of this screen all day for forgetting to assign the class to the storyboard view. My bad. I've implemented the delegate and it's all working as intended now. 

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please post an answer to your question and mark it correct (or maybe @Rob wants to do it) so the next person who finds this can see the correct solution. Right now, there's just an up-voted (well intended, but incorrect) answer posted that will be of no use to anyone visiting here later.

Answer (score 2):

Use the properties to apply the strong modifier:

```
self.responsedata = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
(.....)
self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest: ....etc...
```

Comment: This is better form, but I don't see how it solves the problem.

Comment: @danh: As soon as `viewDidLoad` ends, the connection method goes out of scope and is being deallocated. By strongly holding on to it, it will stay around and call the delegate methods.

Comment: You're right, pre-ARC, but the property is declared strong.  And while it's better form to use the synthesized setter, ARC will insert a retain anyplace you access the property directly.  Your answer was a good one a couple years ago, but not any more.

Comment: @Scott that's generally true, but not for `NSURLConnection`, which retains itself during the connection. I often don't maintain any property for the connection. It's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest putting a `NSLog` or breakpoint in `viewDidLoad` to make sure this is getting called at all. For example, this might happen if you neglected to specify `DownloadUpdates` as the class for your storyboard scene.